# Error building an android project using Samsung S-Pen SDK using Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, samsung-mobile, samsung-mobile-sdk

I integrated SPen and Chord to my company's android game, and as a result when i try to build the app with obfuscation i'm getting the following error (warning - its a long one):

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
Proguard Error 1 
Output: 
Warning: android.sec.multiwindow.Constants$WindowManagerPolicy: can't find referenced class android.view.WindowManagerPolicy 
Warning: android.sec.multiwindow.MultiWindowManager: can't find referenced method 'java.util.List getRunningTasks(int,int,android.app.IThumbnailReceiver)' in class android.app.ActivityManager 
Warning: com.google.common.base.Absent: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable 
Warning: com.google.common.base.Absent: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable 
Warning: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue 
Warning: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue 
Warning: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue 
Warning: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue 
Warning: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue 
Warning: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue 
Warning: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue 
Warning: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue 
Warning: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue 
.
.
.
.
Warning: com.samsung.sdraw.CanvasView: can't find referenced field 'android.text.Layout$Alignment ALIGN_LEFT' in class android.text.Layout$Alignment 
Warning: com.samsung.sdraw.CanvasView: can't find referenced field 'android.text.Layout$Alignment ALIGN_RIGHT' in class android.text.Layout$Alignment 
Warning: com.samsung.sdraw.CanvasView: can't find referenced method 'void setCursorColor(int)' in class com.samsung.sdraw.t 
Warning: com.samsung.sdraw.PresetListItem: can't find referenced method 'void setHoverPopupType(int)' in class android.widget.ImageButton 
Warning: com.samsung.sdraw.ad: can't find referenced method 'void setHoverPopupType(int)' in class android.view.View 
Warning: com.samsung.sdraw.ae: can't find referenced method 'void setHoverPopupType(int)' in class android.view.View 
Warning: com.samsung.sdraw.bf: can't find referenced method 'void setHoverPopupType(int)' in class android.view.View 
Warning: com.samsung.sdraw.bf: can't find referenced method 'void setHoverPopupType(int)' in class com.samsung.sdraw.CustomSeekBar 
Warning: com.samsung.sdraw.bf: can't find referenced method 'void setHoverPopupType(int)' in class com.samsung.sdraw.dl 
Warning: com.samsung.sdraw.bg: can't find referenced method 'void setHoverPopupType(int)' in class android.view.View 
Warning: com.samsung.sdraw.bg: can't find referenced method 'void setHoverPopupType(int)' in class com.samsung.sdraw.CustomSeekBar 
Warning: com.samsung.sdraw.bg: can't find referenced method 'void setHoverPopupType(int)' in class com.samsung.sdraw.dl 
Warning: com.samsung.sdraw.bo: can't find referenced method 'void setHoverPopupType(int)' in class android.widget.ImageButton 
Warning: com.samsung.sdraw.dh: can't find referenced method 'void setHoverPopupType(int)' in class com.samsung.sdraw.dl 
Warning: com.samsung.sdraw.di: can't find referenced method 'void setHoverPopupType(int)' in class com.samsung.sdraw.dl 
Warning: com.samsung.sdraw.w: can't find referenced method 'void setHoverPopupType(int)' in class android.widget.SeekBar 
Warning: com.samsung.sdraw.x: can't find referenced method 'void setHoverPopupType(int)' in class android.widget.SeekBar 
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars. 
Warning: there were 1071 unresolved references to classes or interfaces. 
         You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars'). 
Warning: there were 18 unresolved references to program class members. 
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent. 
         You may need to recompile them and try again. 
         Alternatively, you may have to specify the option  
         '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'. 
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first. 
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321) 
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211) 
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86) 
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

The SPen libraries are somehow involved in this error, but i'm using the 2.3 version so it should be fixed.
Any help will be appreciated!